# JQuery loop through each div id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i am trying to use jquery to loop through each div tag with id = "rate". jquery would then preform function on the seperate divs. here's my code:

**info.html**

```
 <html>
  <input class="rate" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rate;?>" /></p>
  <div class='rating_bar'>
  <!-- div element that contains full stars with percentage width, 
  which represents rating -->
  <div  class="rating" style='width:40%;'>
  </div>
  </div>
  </html>
```

**rate.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.rate').each(function( index ){
    var value = this.value;
    if(value >= 0 && value <= 5)
      {
     value = Math.round((value/5)*100);
     $('.rating').each(function(){
     $(this).width(value + '%');
          }
      }}
      else
       {
      alert("Incorrect value, rating must be between 0 and 5");
        }
          });
       });
```

**style.css**

```
   .rating_bar {
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
   background: url(../images/rate-btn2.png); 
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   background-position: 0 0;
   text-align: left;
    }
  .rating {

   height: 40px;
   background: url(../images/rate-btn2-hover.png);
   background-position: 0 -1px;
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
     }
```

**Question:**

what i have are multiple hidden textboxes with div id="rate". jquery only affects first div id.how do loop through each div id?

Comment: you cannot have multiple divs with same `ID`

Comment: use class instead of ID. That's what classes are for ... multiple instances

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla , I've  replaced id with class, still not working :(

Comment: did you change the selector to a class selector?

Comment: In the `each` part you can replace `document.getElementById("rate").value;` with `$(this).val()`, or `this.value` to get the value of the input you are iterating over.

Comment: Formatting is weird, and you are missing a closing brace before the `else` statement

Comment: @MichaelP. , dont mean to bother but could you please help in correcting the formatting. i'm unsure where to put the brace you're referring to.

Comment: Before the else, you should have `)}` instead of `}}`. That is to say, we first close the `each` function with a brace, then we close the `if` with a curly brace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace :

```
$('.rate').each(function( index ){
    var value = document.getElementById("rate").value;
    // ...
});
```

with :

```
$('.rate').each(function( index ){
    var value = this.value;
    // ...
});
```

to get the value of the `input` element you are iterating over.

---

Edit. Based on your comments, you need to link the *n-th* `div.rating` with the value of the *n-th* `input.rate`. For that we can use the `.eq` function of jQuery, to get the n-th child of an array of elements. See code below :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.rate').each(function (index) {
         var value = this.value;
         if (value >= 0 && value <= 5) {
             value = Math.round((value / 5) * 100);
             $('.rating').eq(index).width(value + '%');
             //          ^^^
             //          We get the corresponding .rating element
         } else {
             alert("Incorrect value, rating must be between 0 and 5");
         }
     });
 });
```

And here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/447b2x9e/3/)

Comment: thanks but it seems that the value of the last div is used for the others.

Comment: i'm getting the same value for all divs

Comment: You mean the same value for all `'.rate'` elements ?

Comment: yes, that is i get the same result everytime. the value is correct after changing the type from 'hidden' to 'text' to make sure. but i get the same result for all values with div class 'rate'

Comment: Here is a fiddle of what I see, based on your code and the corrections : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/447b2x9e/) Is that what you get?

Comment: exactly. the result should be 1 star, 3 stars, 4stars.

Comment: If I understand well, you want the first `div.rating` to equal the value of the first `input.rate`, the second div with the second input and so on. Is that it?

Comment: Thanks alot, i should buy you  a drink. quick question: since i'm using php to echo the value of rate from a database, do i have to enter the div class 'rating-bar' as many times i echo '$rate'?. As users can review an item and i would have to manually edit the php file so it shows the actual rating value

Comment: Well, the `rating-bar` elements should be generated as well as you are generating the `.rate` elements. No need to do manual things. Did that answer your question?

Comment: @MichaelP., Could you help me with my [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218251/jquery-getting-display-of-value-when-there-is-multiple-of-the-same-id)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `ID`s SHOULD be unique in programming world. Anyways you should change your markup to use class instead of ID. See:

```
<div class="rate">800</div>
```

Then you can use jquery to get the text inside that div:

```
$('.rate').each(function(){
    var textValue = this.text();
    // anything you want to do here.
});
```

**Note**: `this` refers to the current jquery object inside the loop.