# jQuery | Getting display of value when there is multiple of the same ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a jQuery function (follows:

```
$(this).ready(function () {
    $("#stake").on('keyup', function () {
        var newVal = (parseFloat($("#stake").val(), 10) * parseFloat($('#__odds').val(), 10)) + parseFloat($("#stake").val(), 10) || 0;
        $("#showdynamicreturn").val(parseFloat(newVal).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

) and I have more than one attribute with the same ID, this means that I need to get the function to allow for more than one thing to change it, what is the best way to go about this?
Also I want the new value to be added to the value displayed in the `showdynamicreturn` area for each one that is typed in, how do I do this?

*Example*
1) User input 1 - return f 2
2) User input 2 - return of 4
Displayed in `showdynamicreturn` - 6

***HTML code here***

```
<div style="border: 1pt solid black; width: 99%;">
    <h2>1:55 Scottsville - Win</h2>
    <form action="/sports/football/" method="post">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%;">Sport: </td>
                    <td>Horse Racing</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%">Participant: </td>
                    <td>Legend Dancer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Market: </td>
                    <td>Scottsville</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Time: </td>
                    <td>13:55</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Odds: </td>
                    <td>8/1<input type="hidden" value="8" id="__odds"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Stake: </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">£</span><input style="width: 100%" type="text" name="stake" id="stake" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" placeholder="Stake"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <center><label for="eachWay">Each way bet?&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input type="checkbox" id="eachWay" name="eachWay"></center>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <center><input type="submit" name="submitTo__OpenBets" value="Open Bet"></center>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="betslip_id" value="36"><input type="hidden" name="sport" value="football"><input type="hidden" name="odds" value="8/1"><input type="hidden" name="sport" value="Horse Racing"><input type="hidden" name="bettilldate" value="2015-05-13"><input type="hidden" name="bettilltime" value="13:55:00">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="100%">
                        <center><input type="submit" name="delete_betslip_item" value="Delete this bet"></center>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

***Generating code:***

```
public function ReadBets_Bet($id, $currentpage, $loggedIn = true) {
    $queryBase = "SELECT * FROM `vr_wp_bets` WHERE `id` = '%s' AND `is_open` = 'false' ORDER BY `sport` ASC;";
    if ($loggedIn == true) {
        $queryBase2 = sprintf($queryBase, $id);
    }
    else {
        $queryBase2 = sprintf($queryBase, $id);
    }
    $selectQuery = mysql_query($queryBase2);
    $return = "<div style='max-height: 400px; overflow: scroll;'>";
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($selectQuery)) {
        $_odds = explode("/", $result['odds']);
        $odds = $_odds[0] / $_odds[1];
        $return .= "<div style='border: 1pt solid black; width: 99%;'>";
        $return .= "<h2>" . $result['title'] . "</h2>";
        $return .= "<form action='/sports/" . CURRENT_PAGE . "/' method='post'>";
        $return .= "<table>";

        $return .= "<tr><td style='width:50%;'>Sport: </td><td>" . $result['sport'] . "</td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td style='width:50%'>Participant: </td><td>" . stripslashes($result['participant']) . "</td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td>Market: </td><td>" . stripslashes($result['market']) . "</td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td>Time: </td><td>" . date("H:i", strtotime($result['bettilltime'])) . "</td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td>Odds: </td><td>" . $result['odds'] . "<input type='hidden' value='" . $odds . "' id='__odds' /></td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td>Stake: </td><td><div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>&pound;</span><input style='width:100%' type='text' name='stake' id='stake' aria-describedby='basic-addon1' placeholder='Stake' /></div></td></tr>";


        if ($result['ew_available'] == "true") {
            $return .= "<tr><td><center><label for='eachWay'>Each way bet?&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input type='checkbox' id='eachWay' name='eachWay' /></center></td>" .  "<td><center><input type='submit' name='submitTo__OpenBets' value='Open Bet' /></center></td></tr>";
        }
        else {                
            $return .=  "<tr><td colspan='10'><center><input type='submit' name='submitTo__OpenBets' value='Place Bet' /></center></td></tr>";
        }

        $return .= "<!-- Hidden fields for the horses information. -->";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='betslip_id' value='" . $result['bet_id'] . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='sport' value='" . $currentpage . "' />";

        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='odds' value='" . $result['odds'] . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='sport' value='" . $result['sport'] . "' />";

        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='bettilldate' value='" . $result['bettilldate'] . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='bettilltime' value='" . $result['bettilltime'] . "' />";

        $return .= "<!-- Area to \"submit a delete\" and remove an item from the bet slip. -->";
        $return .= "<tr><td colspan='100%'><center><input type='submit' name='delete_betslip_item' value='Delete this bet' /></center></td></tr>";
        $return .= "</table>";
        $return .= "</form>";
        $return .= "</div><br>";
    }
    $return .= "</div>";
    $return .= "<tr id='dynamic_return'><td colspan='10'><center><div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon2'>&pound;</span><input style='width:100%' type='text' id='showdynamicreturn' aria-describedby='basic-addon2' placeholder='0.00' readonly /></div></center></td></tr>";
    //$return .= $queryBase2;
    return $return;
}
```

***NOTE***
mysql_* functions are used (yes I know depreciated) due to client needs and requirements.

***EDIT***

The jQuery I now have:

```
var count_div = 0;
$(this).ready(function () {
    $("div").each(function () {
        ++count_div;
        console.log("Counter: " + count_div);
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < count_div; ++i) {
        $("#stake-" + i).each(function () {
            console.log("Found stake " + i);
        });
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < count_div; ++i) {
        $("#__odds-" + i).each(function () {
            console.log("Found stake " + i);
        });
    }
    $("#showdynamicreturn").each(function () {
        console.log("Found text area");
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < count_div; ++i) {
        $("#stake-" + i).on('keyup', function () {
            var newVal = (parseFloat($("#stake-" + i).val(), 10) * parseFloat($("#__odds-" + i).val(), 10)) + parseFloat($("#stake-" + i).val(), 10) || 0;
            $("#showdynamicreturn").val(parseFloat(newVal).toFixed(2));
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that, as IDs must be unique within the tree ([stated in the spec at 3.2.5.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)).

When duplicate IDs are present -- which most browsers will permit -- the return order of them is at best undefined and at worst you will only retrieve a single element.

The simplest solution, which should work with your code, is to append a numeric suffix to the ID to enforce uniqueness. You may be able to use a unique identifier that already exists in your data or, if you have a loop, simply keep a counter and append that to a fixed string. `foo-1` will work much better than multiple `foo`s.

With numeric IDs, you'll need to modify your jQ function to be something like:

```
var items = 100;
$(this).ready(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < items; ++i) {
    $("#stake-" + i).on('keyup', function () {
      var newVal = (parseFloat($("#stake-" + i).val(), 10) * parseFloat($('#__odds').val(), 10)) + parseFloat($("#stake-" + i).val(), 10) || 0;
      $("#showdynamicreturn-" + i).val(parseFloat(newVal).toFixed(2));
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: How would I add this to the jQuery function though? Surely I'd need to loop that too to get the right value?

Comment: @SamSwift Correct. I added a quick example of how that might go. You'll need to record the total number of records somewhere. You posted enough code that I'm not 100% sure how the program flows through it, but hopefully this is enough to put you on the right track.

Comment: so I would use a function to count each of the divs in the page (this will be greater than what's needed), then loop through this to get each of the ID's?

Comment: I have added the code I now have at the bottom of my question

Comment: Thanks to the placeholder I have in the `showdynamicreturn` area, I can see that the function is beign called and used, however it is not showing the value in it

Comment: You'll need to modify the PHP code to append counters to the IDs when the elements are created, as well.

Comment: I added functions to find all the elements with `stake- i` and `__odds- i` and the `showdynamic return`. All these are found and logged however it doesn't add the value to `showdynamicreturn`